# How to unit test a method with dependencies in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have a method with some logic in it and I'm not sure how to unit test it. Because it's a unit test for this specific method it should run without connecting to the database. I read about stubs and mockups but I can't find a way to apply them to this situation.

I would like to force the Client:GetClient to return the client object with the right properties so I can test each logic branch.

```
class ClientType {
    function GetClientType($id) {

    $objClient = Client::GetClient($id);

    if ($objClient->Returning == 1) {
        return 'returning';
    }
    else {
        return 'normal';
    }
    }
```

This is the test I had in mind

```
class ResourceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testGetClientType() {
        $objClientType = new ClientType();
        $this->assertTrue($objClientType->GetClientType(100), 'normal');
    }
}
```

The problem is the dependency $objClient = Client::GetClient($id); The GetClient will pull a client from database but I need to replace this with a Stub so the unit tests work without real access to the database.

### Conclusion

If you have code like the one presented: refactor it and use Dependency Injection.

If you have legacy code or just don't want to refactor try this solution: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html

Comment: is this for a specific unit testing framework?

Comment: @gordon - no specific framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) you can do

```
  $class = $this->getMockClass(
      'Client',          /* name of class to mock     */
      array('getClient') /* list of methods to mock   */
    );
    $class::staticExpects($this->any())
          ->method('getClient')
          ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));
```

In general, you want to avoid static methods though:

- [http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524091248/http://sebastian-bergmann.de:80/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html)
- https://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

---

**EDIT after update**

PHPUnit can also stub hardcoded dependencies. See

- [Stubbing Hard-Coded Dependencies](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524091248/http://sebastian-bergmann.de:80/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html) by Sebastian Bergmann

However, since you already noticed by now that it is a Pain the Behind to test statics and hardcoded dependencies, I suggest you remove the hardcoded dependency and static call with a real object that you inject into your ClientType instead.

Another option would be to use http://antecedent.github.io/patchwork (not affiliated with it), which

> is a PHP library that makes it possible to redefine user-defined functions and methods 
>   at runtime, loosely replicating the functionality runkit_function_redefine in pure PHP 5.3 code,
>   which, among other things, enables you to replace static and private methods with test doubles.

Comment: @gordon, but my goal is to test the function GetClientType, isn't your code testing the Client class?

Comment: @danip My code is stubbing (!= testing) the static `Client::getClient()` to return foo whenever it's called. If this does not solve your problem, please update your question to point out what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @gordon - I understand your stubbing the Client but how is that solving the unit testing of the function GetClientType, what i'm trying to do is make the GetClientType use the stub

Comment: @danip Sorry, it seems I don't understand the problem here. All you do is call `$class::getClient()` then and it will return whatever you configured it to return. So if it's supposed to return an Object, make it return an object.

Comment: @gordon - but this mean it's a good practice to avoid creating objects inside methods ?

Comment: @danip Yes. You are supposed to use Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try Mocking for such kind of a problem. I do not know PHP, but we do mocking in Java and C# in such a scenario.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry I didn't see that you were facing a problem with mocks. Well usually for Mocks you tell them what you expect from them and they respond to the same. LSV principle is being used in mocks. As for PHP, I'm sorry I have no idea on what tool to use for mocks and how you use them

Comment: In php there is a problem mocking a static method (with phpunit) so in java do you mock Client::GetClient ?

Comment: @danip: yes, we do it that way in Java. But, I'm sure there is a way to achieve this in PHP too. Lets wait for others reply to this thread.